# Issues reconnecting PS4 controller to console after using iPad

Tags: ps4

Any suggestions on how to reconnect my ps4 controller to console?
I recently connected it to the iPad to play and now I can’t seem to reconnect to console. I have reset the small button in back and connected it to console with usb cable but it’s not connecting

Comment: Have you plugged in the controller (turned off state) with a USB cable and then hit the PS button to turn it on, while it is connected to a turned on PS4?